# How do I copy only files that overwrite others in a directory

Tags: copy

I want to copy and overwrite only files that exist in the destination. Aka excluding 'lonely files' that exist in the source xor the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this with `rsync`, using the `--existing` flag:

> ```
>         --existing              skip creating new files on receiver
> ```

Ex. given

```
$ tree -a A/ B/
A/
├── bar
├── baz
├── foo
└── .hidden
B/
├── bam
├── baz
├── foo
└── .hidden
```

0 directories, 8 files

where `baz`, `foo` and `.hidden` are common but `bar` exists only on the source and `bam` only on the target, then (note: I've included the verbose `-v` and `-n` "dry run" flag for the purpose of illustration):

```
$ rsync -avn --existing A/ B/
sending incremental file list
.hidden
baz
foo

sent 152 bytes  received 25 bytes  354.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

only updates `baz`, `foo` and `.hidden`. (Files that exist only on the destination are   ignored by default.)

---

You can verify that without `--existing`, `bar` would also be copied:

```
$ rsync -avn A/ B/
sending incremental file list
.hidden
bar
baz
foo

sent 155 bytes  received 28 bytes  366.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00 (DRY RUN)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, does this copy hidden files as well?

Comment: @EmergencyTemporalShift yes I believe it will - see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on stackoverflow. There are several solutions. I didnt try them but I think they should work and solve your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154327/move-or-copy-a-file-if-that-file-exists?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Hope it helps you. ;)